# Vb .net Compare two text file

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm, compare

I have a program written in .net 2.0 and I need to compare two text files.
I've tried the following code

```
Dim fileA As String
Dim fileB As String
Dim fileypath As String = (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA") & "\ARLS\")
Dim sReaderA As New IO.StreamReader(New IO.FileStream(fileypath & "orig.dat", IO.FileMode.Open))
Dim sReaderB As New IO.StreamReader(New IO.FileStream(fileypath & "comp.dat", IO.FileMode.Open))
fileA = sReaderA.ReadToEnd
fileB = sReaderB.ReadToEnd
sReaderA.Close()
sReaderB.Close()
If fileA.CompareTo(fileB) = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show(fileB.Replace(fileA, "")) '/// show the words in fileB which differ from fileA.
End If
If fileB.CompareTo(fileA) = -1 Then
    MessageBox.Show(fileA.Replace(fileB, "")) '/// show the words in fileB which differ from fileB.
End If
```

And it works except that it will only show if something is added to the end of the line. If anything is added or deleted in the middle, it will show the entire text file.
Any ideas.
**<--EDIT-->**
So I got it working by creating two list boxes, dumping the text files into each then comparing the list boxes with the following code. `For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            If ListBox1.Items.Contains(ListBox2.Items(i)) Then
            Else
                LogPrint(ListBox2.Items(i))
            End If
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            If ListBox2.Items.Contains(ListBox1.Items(i)) Then
            Else
                LogPrint(ListBox1.Items(i))
            End If
        Next
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()`
This gives me the differences but that seems like a long way arround. Anyone know if there is a better way to do it without using listboxes?

Comment: That's just how String.Compare() works.  Clearly it is not much of a difference analyzing engine.  Google "vb.net text diff".

Comment: I have Googled it but all that I have come across will only tell me if they are different not what actually has changed or requires **.net 4.5**

Comment: Determining what has changed is a very difficult problem to solve.  I've never found a file comparer application that is 100% accurate, and that's coming from applications that do nothing but that.  I'm sure you could find some algorithms online that may be good enough for what you need, but there is certainly no built-in method or class in the .NET framework for doing what you want.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this question?  Could the person who did it, comment?  No one is going to get better when all you do is down vote with no comment?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a simple problem. In fact, sometimes there is more than one solution that is equally good. For example, if file A contains "141" and B contains "1441", was the new "4" inserted at the 2nd or 3rd character? So there is no single .net function to accomplish this. You might be able to find an open source library with this capability, though.

One way to solve the problem is to find the [longest common substring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) of the files, then do the same recursively over the remaining halves until there are no more common substrings (longer than a minimum size).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to determine whether they're identical? If so, comparing the byte array on both might be the best way to do so.

Comment: No I need to know what the difference is. It will only be a line or two but the line change or deletion could be anywhere in either file

Comment: I see. Well, here's some pseudocode in C# (sorry, I develop in C#, and I'm nowhere near Visual Studio...)

Answer (score -1):

Would something like this work?

```
public void CheckFiles() {

//iterate through files...

    using (StreamReader r1 = new StreamReader("file1")) {

          using (StreamReader r2 = new StreamReader("file2")) {

                 while (!r1.EndOfStream && !rs.EndOfStream ) {

                      bool areLinesIdentical = compareLines(r1.readLine(), r2.readLine());

                      if (!areLinesIdentical) {

                      Console.WriteLine("These two lines do not match!" + r1.readLine() + " and " + r2.readLine());

                      }

                 }


             }


       }

}


    private static bool compareLines(string s1, string s2) {

    if (s1 == s2) { return true; }

    else { return false; }

    }
```

Comment: Let me try it out and see but from looking at the code it could not distinguish if a line was removed and everything was shifted up. For instant if **File1** has 5 lines and **File2** has 4 lines but the difference is that line 3 from **File1** is not in **File2** so it would return a result of lines 3 - 5

Comment: Gotcha. Then, you could probably do a try/catch on each readline, compare the results, and at some point you'll find that one line is empty (by way of the catch) while the other has something. Makes sense?